# Untiy2D Tilemap has gaps in it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason I keep getting these weird gaps in between my tile maps, any suggestions?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is regarding how the pixels are "snapped" to the camera, and how the resolution on the camera is, compared with your pixel sizes.

At this post in the Unity3d forum, there are multiple suggestions on how to fix it. You can try some of them.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/tilemap-has-tearing-between-tiles-even-with-pixel-snap.499154/